# .NET Core 6 Update-database on server after migration on local machine

Tags: .net, sql-server, migration, .net-6.0

After releasing my application to the server, I like now to make some update on my database (on the server).

In my application I'm using `DbContext` (IIdentitycore) then with Nuget manager console generate migration then make `update-database`, so the database in local is updated.

But now how to apply this update to my database on the server? Is there any why to generate an update SQL query?

I'm using .NET 6 and SQL Server Express.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate migration scripts using [Powershell or CLI commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#sql-scripts):

```
Script-Migration
```

```
dotnet ef migrations script
```

Or by generating [bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#bundles) executable file or just applying migrations [at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime) at the start of the app.